# How to implement the standard normal cumulative distribution function in C (or other language)

Tags: c, probability, normal-distribution, quantitative-finance, probability-theory

First of all, for those of you who don't know this law, don't be afraid it's actually pretty simple.
On this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model you will see this law from a mathematical point of view.
Go on the section notation and look at the function that starts by N(x)=1/sqrt(2*PI)...
I am implementing the Black-Scholes model in C as you might have guess and I don't know how to implement this function, I have found an implementation online but I am not sure if I should be happy about it, it seems a little off.
This is the code I am using.

```
double N(double z){
    const double b1=0.31938153;
    const double b2=-0.356563782;
    const double b3=1.781477937;
    const double b4=-1.821255978;
    const double b5=1.330274429;
    const double p=0.2316419;

    double a=fabs(z);
    double t=1.0/(1.0+a*p);
    double w=1.0-1.0/sqrt(2*M_PI)*exp(-a*a/2)*(b1*t+b2*t*t+b3*pow(t,3)+b4*pow(t,4)+b5*pow(t,5));
    if(z<0.0)
        w=1.0-w;
    return w;
}
```

What I would like is for you to tell me if this implementation of the law is correct and why it is.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What seems a little off about it?

Comment: Well I am checking the results I get with those of an other program and they are a bit different, I have no way of knowing who have the better the implementation so this is way I wanted to know if my implementation is correct and if it is why it is.

Comment: Suggest posting various results you get from this code and other results from other methods that are a "bit different".

Comment: Note: `t*(b1 + t*(b2* + t*(b3 + t*(b4 + t*b5))))` is mathematically more stable than `b1*t+b2*t*t+b3*pow(t,3)+b4*pow(t,4)+b5*pow(t,5)` and likely faster.

Comment: OK, thank you but is my implementation correct ? And why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard normal cumulative distribution function is exactly `(1/2)*(1 + erf(z/sqrt(2)))` where `erf` is the Gaussian error function, which is found in many C programming libraries. Check the development environment you are using -- chances are good that `erf` is already in one of its libraries.

Comment: For example, on Linux ( http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/erf.3.html ); on Windows ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308428.aspx ); in Boost (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_erf/error_function.html ).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check later ans will let you know.

Comment: Quick update, erf is in math.h as said by Robert Dodier. I've implemented his solution and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.